# In science fiction films and anime, why do we see some planets are close in the sky?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, science-fiction

It's very common to see this view but in reality, our earth doesn't have that one. We only have one Moon orbiting around our Mother planet. In sci-fi movies what is this term commonly called? Most western movies some Japanese sci-fi anime includes that view.

For example in the 2009 science fiction film *Avatar*, you can see there is a planet seen in the sky:

[image: 3 images showing a large gas giant in the sky]

It looked like Jupiter but the planet is Polyphemus.

Here's a promotional photo of the movie *Avatar* with a fantasy landscape view, where a planet is seen in the sky:

[image: daytime shot with the planet in the background, shows 2 main characters in the foreground in the water]

In the 2014 dieselpunk sci-fi movie *Garm Wars: The Last Druid By Mamoru Oshii*, we can also see one planet in the sky called "Gaia":

[image: planet peeking behind clouds]

The 1985 retro futuristic anime series *Dirty Pair* we also see the landscape of a futuristic city "Eleanor" where planets are also seen on the night cloudy sky, one is a large planet and one small planet are seen in the sky:

[image: Eleanor City skyscape]

Daytime view of the planets in the sky on Eleanor City

[image: Damocles Tower Landscape With A Planets On A Daytime Sky]

Why did the director or the creator put some planets like these in the sky like this?

Comment: Some sci-fi movies with planets are seen in the sky like:

Star Wars,
Foundation series,
Altered Carbon and
Star Trek

Comment: I feel this is more for aesthetics

Comment: In the Zorro computer animated series it always shows the Moon like it is very close to the Earth.

Comment: Because it looks cool?

Comment: It's called 'Hollywood'.

Comment: TVTropes ALERT! This page may provide you with some clues. Along with some 200 other pages you'll end up on... https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SciFiWritersHaveNoSenseOfScale

Comment: You can get real pictures similar to this naturally on earth [with telephoto setups](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34517/how-do-people-shoot-very-large-moon-views). [This stunning eclipse shot](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2167595/Stunning-image-shows-boy-watching-solar-eclipse--taken-1-5-miles-away.html) is a bold example, shot with a long lens and a teleconverter from 1.5 miles away. Some of [Gary Hershorn's work](https://twitter.com/garyhershorn/status/1055602768164110336) is in this family as well.

Comment: .... to emphasize that they're not on Earth?

Comment: (At least two movies show a large, close planet realistically — _2001: A Space Odyssey_ and its sequel — but that's coz the cast are _in orbit_ around it. And they're not _on_ a planet at the time. So they don't count for this question. But it _does_ look cool…)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most direct answer to  your question, is that the director thought it improved the visuals of his production.

Some of those directors will have put some thought into how to justify such a view in their sky and will come up with the exact placement and orbits that will allow such a view.

Other directors will just decide they want a particular view, and not care how such a view could realistically take place, or whether it would realistically be possible.

Both of these are perfectly valid choices, though a story with a more realistic or hard sci-fi setting should probably lean heavily towards a more physically realistic scene.

Answer (score 55):

Your question could be interpreted as either:

- **Our Earth doesn't have a view like this.  What is different about these planets that makes this view correct?**  The answer to this is simple.  Earth is a planet, with a smaller orbiting moon.  Both examples of inhabited "planets" you show here (Panora and Annwn) are smaller moons orbiting larger planets.  You would expect, especially in the case of Pandora, orbiting a much larger gas-giant, to see this represented in the sky.
- **Or why do the writers and directors choose a situation like this for their stories?**  This is a little harder to have a distinct verifyable answer since it may vary from story to story.  However it does provide a distinctly alien view to the world which adds to the aesthetic of a science fiction movie, much in the same way as Tatooine's two suns do so in Star Wars.  Also, it simply looks pretty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :D , So the answer is a "Alien World Environment" ?

Comment: It's not *that* alien. For example, if you look at the Moon from Earth, the Moon looks rather small … because it *is* small compared to Earth. But if you look at Earth from the Moon, it looks much, much bigger … because it *is* much, much bigger. Jupiter has 11 times the diameter of Earth but is only twice as far away from Europa as Earth is from the Moon, so Jupiter would appear roughly 5 times bigger from Europa than Earth from the Moon. As mentioned in the answer, Pandora is also a moon orbiting a gas giant, so the gas giant would look … giant.

Comment: See here for an artist's rendering of what it might look like standing on the surface of Europa: https://europa.nasa.gov/resources/34/simulated-view-from-europas-surface/

Comment: @OwenAyanami perhaps a clearly "different world" rather than "alien world" might be better wording?

Comment: Is there even a case where it would be possible to have a planet in the sky that big other than a tidally locked moon orbiting it?  Wouldn't a world that close otherwise raise tides that would make it uninhabitable?

Comment: Since the moon seperates from the earth each year for about 3-5 centimeter [ which, in fact, causes the tides in the ocean ], shooting a movie about the jura age would actually display a giant moon in the skies

Comment: @LorenPechtel the tides would probably make a lot of the coastal regions uninhabitable. But that doesn't mean that more inland areas are

Comment: @Hobbamok Tides move land as well as water.  The effect is smaller but if the tides are strong enough you get nasty effects.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm not sure I buy this explanation. The size of the planet you're looking from has no effect on the appearing size of the planet you're looking at. Unless you meant something different...?

Comment: Sometimes it's explicit: in *Return of the Jedi*, “the forest moon of Endor” and the second Death Star both orbit the same giant planet, and their relative positions in orbit are (briefly) relevant to the story.

Answer (score 3):

The question asker obviously hasn't seen a lot of old science fiction movies and tv shows or they would have mentioned some other examples, as in *Str Trek: The Motion Picture* and on Rigel VII in "The Cage"/"Menagerie" in *Star Trek: The Original Series*.

I have seen many films where Earth's Moon looks vast as seen from Earth.  Those films were shot with telephoto lenses to make the Moon look far larger than it would be seen with the naked eye.

And certainly viewers can suppose that some of the scenes showing worlds in the sky of alien worlds might be normal vision and some might be what you would see though telephoto lenses, thus making the worlds in the sky look much wider than they would with the naked eye.

I believe there was a question asking what would be the greatest angular diameter of another world seen from a habitable world.  I think that was in the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange.  And different answers gave different maximum angles - even the smallest being several times as wide as the Moon as seen from Earth.

Here are links to related Worldbuilding questions:

- [Maximum size of a visible planet without effects on my world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108254/maximum-size-of-a-visible-planet-without-effects-on-my-world/108276#108276)
- [Can huge planets be seen from tiny planets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/150326/can-huge-planets-be-seen-from-tiny-planets/150366#150366)
- [What is the largest possible appearance of a celestial body in the
  sky?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/199722/what-is-the-largest-possible-appearance-of-a-celestial-body-in-the-sky/199765#199765)

Answer (score 1):

There's a great explination in the below video

Big things closer would be easier to see. It just so happens that everything near the Earth is far away for us to see.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks also for the answer, i have also seen this one but generally i can't gather much solid answers from this one

Answer (score 1):

I can answer this for Avatar - the story takes place on a moon of the larger gas-giant planet - in this case the scales would be correct, as it would be if we were stood on Enceladus, we'd see Saturn in a similar way. No idea for other films though sorry, well other than aesthetics anyway.